# Ionic customize existing UI components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

How should I go about trying to customize an existing UI component beyond the scope of its provided SASS variables?

For example, I would like customize the borders of `ion-navbar` and make the design flat for both iOS and Android. There's the possibility of creating a component from scratch, but I was wondering if it's possible to just customize existing the `ion-navbar` beyond the scope of tweaking its SASS variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the documentation carefully, I found the answer here:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-specific-styles/#overriding-the-mode-styles

We just need to add `.md` and `.ios` css class to a component we want to customize. For example, to customize a button:

```
.md .ios .button {
  /* Your custom css here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code for ion-navbar in "node_modules" > "ionic-angular" > "components" > "toolbar" and customized from there.

However, I would highly recommend you to create your own custom navbar component and use it from there.